# why my javascript is showing value not founded?

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary-search

I am trying to do a binary search in an array but my javascript is showing no value founded even when I entered a number that in the array in the prompt input

```js
var array = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 95, 100, 102, 105, 200, 250, 300, 320, 350];
var search = parseInt(prompt("enter what you search for"));
var first = 0,
  last = array.length - 1,
  position = 0,
  middle, flag = false;

while ((flag == false) && (first <= last)) {
  middle = ((first + last) / 2);
  if (array[middle] == search) {
    flag = true;
    position = middle;
  } else
  if (array[middle] > search)
    last = middle - 1;

  else
    first = middle + 1;
}
if (flag)
  document.write("</br>value founded in position  " + position);
else
  document.write("</br>value not founded ");
```

Comment: add debugging: `console.log(middle)` will give you `8.5`, there is no number at index 8.5

Answer (score 2):

> middle value calculation.

```
 middle = Math.round(first + ((last - first) / 2));
```

// Your code..

```
var array =[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,95,100,102,105,200,250,300,320,350] ;
var search= 20; //parseInt(prompt ("enter what you search for"));

var first=0, last=array.length-1, 
position=0,
middle ,
flag=false;

while((flag==false) && (first <=last)) {
 middle = Math.round(first + ((last - first) / 2)); //((first+last)/2); low + (last - low)/2
 if (array[middle]==search){
     flag=true;
     position=middle ;
 }else if(array[middle]>search) {
     last=middle-1 ;
 }
 else {
    first= middle+1;
 }

}
if (flag) 
document.write ("</br>value founded in position  "+position);
else
document.write("</br>value not founded ");
```

Answer (score 0):

For now when you do `middle = ((first + last) / 2);` it puts the number with floating point to the middle. However, you need to have integer number here. In order to make it you should wrap your calculation with `Math.round()` or `Math.floor()`.

So you will get:

```
middle = Math.round((first + last) / 2);
```